# How to upload CSV file to BigQuery Using the BigQuery SQL code

Tags: file-upload, google-bigquery, upload

Anyone knows how to upload local CSV file to Bigquery using the bigquery SQL code not python or bigquery web UI.

please give some tips

thanks.

Comment: See here ... https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#sql

But you won't be able to load into BQ from a "local" CSV because the SQL will run in BQ in the Cloud and won't have access to a CSV file on your local laptop filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to reference a local file directly from SQL code.

The closest you can get is right click on your Dataset -> Create Table.  From here you will be able to select the local file (provided its not too big) and import into BigQuery.

Alternatively, upload the file to cloud storage and then use SQL to import External Table e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE mydataset.sales
  OPTIONS (
  format = 'CSV',
  uris = ['gs://mybucket/sales.csv']);
```